# How to calculate additional purchase

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, math, excel-formula

Let's consider a scenario where I own 100 shares, each initially purchased at an average price of $10 per share. However, the current market value of these shares has decreased, with the present market price for each share being $5. My objective is to determine the number of additional shares I should acquire at the current market price of $5 per share. The goal is that it will enable me to effectively reduce the average cost of all my acquired shares to $6 per share, through the use of an Excel formula.

I need to identify the closest number of share to be purchased as a output.

Googlesheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AcLg4YGfGxRxocjgSUhRfGtGY7Qxt5diK9BEpqRX28E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Excel or Googlesheets? but this is a maths problem.

Comment: You need to solve for x: (100*10+x*5)/(x+100)=6 and in this case x=400

Comment: Added formula to B5 in your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more math than Excel or Sheets question, but here you go:

```
=(B3*B2-B3*B4)/(B1-B2)
```

Result:

[image]